# What is failing in this simple code jquery?

Tags: jquery

Selected According change the value of a text field

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#combo1 option:selected").change(function() {    
        if (this.value == "Egreso"){
            $("#monto").val("-");
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: *Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work.*

Answer (score 4):

The change event fires on the `select` element itself, not the `option` elements within it. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#combo1").change(function() {   
        if ($(this).val() == 'Egreso') {
            $("#monto").val("-");
        }
    })
});
```